# How to register native routines with Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am writing a Bioconductor package. In order to do that, it needs to pass [BiocCheck](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocCheck.html).

I am using Rcpp and Rstudio to make c++ code available to R using the tag `//[[Rcpp::export]]` and Rcpp classes and not SEXP ones. 
Rstudio generates Rcpp_export.cpp and Rcpp_export.R automatically and it works fine.

However, BiocCheck complains about it:

> Checking native routine registration..
>
> Register native routines! see
>         http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Registering-native-routines

So, anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Ask on the Bioconductor [devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/bioc-devel) mailing list (the appropriate location for questions about Bioconductor package development), where you'll probably be told to take the advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: Simplest way: `useDynLib(<pkgName>, <fnNames...>)` in your `NAMESPACE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to register the native routines with Rcpp and passed BiocCheck. I am using Rcpp 0.12.9, BiocCheck 1.9.3 and Kmisc 0.5.1.

1) In the automatically by Rcpp generated file "RcppExports.cpp", add "// [[register]]" before each function in the following place:

```
// my_function
returntype my_function(...);
// [[register]]
RcppExport SEXP packagename_my_function(...) {
BEGIN_RCPP
...
END_RCPP
}
```

2) Then, from R, run

```
Kmisc::registerFunctions(prefix="")
```

This will create a file "packagename_init.c"

3) Make sure you have

```
useDynLib(packagename, .registration=TRUE)
```

in your NAMESPACE file. It also worked without the .registration=TRUE for me.
This should be sufficient to pass BiocCheck. You can check the registered routines with

```
getDLLRegisteredRoutines("packagename")
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested here is the answer I got from the Bioconductor devel mailing list:

"Registering native routines is a best practice, but not required and difficult (I think) to accomplish with Rcpp. I would not expend more effort on this."