# Registering native routines with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, cran

I am trying to get my R package to pass the new constraints in R CMD check. I am unable to do so even though I created the c code under src that should make registering calls

I used  `package_native_routine_registration_skeleton(".")`
to create the RGraphM_init.cpp (I used cpp, because of the substitution I have in Makevars.win)
This is RGraphM_init.cpp

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for NULL
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>


/* .Call calls */
extern SEXP RGraphM_run_graph_match(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP);

    static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
        {"RGraphM_run_graph_match", (DL_FUNC) &RGraphM_run_graph_match, 3},
        {NULL, NULL, 0}
    };

    void R_init_RGraphM(DllInfo *dll)
    {
        R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
        R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
    }
```

I used

```
useDynLib(packagename, .registration=TRUE)
```

in NAMESPACE
    I was assuming the .cpp that includes the registering functions would get picked up by the SHLIB build, but it did not fix the NOTE that there were no calls to  R_useDynamicSymbols and R_regiterRoutines

The snippet of  Makevars.win that is relevant is :

```
SOURCES=  graphmatch_rcpp.cpp RcppExports.cpp RGraphM_init.cpp
OBJECTS= $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(GRAPHM_OBJ_REL)
$(SHLIB): $(OBJECTS)
```

This gives the linking error that  RGraphM_init has undefined ref

```
C:/RBUILD~1/3.4/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RGraphM.dll tmp.def graphmatch_rcpp.o RcppExports.o RGraphM_init.o ./graphm/./algorithm_ca.o ./graphm/./algorithm_ext.o ./graphm/./algorithm_fsol.o ./graphm/./algorithm_iden.o ./graphm/./algorithm_lp.o ./graphm/./algorithm.o ./graphm/./algorithm_path.o ./graphm/./algorithm_qcv.o ./graphm/./algorithm_rand.o ./graphm/./algorithm_rank.o ./graphm/./algorithm_umeyama.o ./graphm/./algorithm_unif.o ./graphm/./experiment.o ./graphm/./graph.o ./graphm/./hungarian.o ./graphm/./rpc.o -LC:\tools\local\/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -LC:\tools\local\lib/i386 -lgsl -lgslcblas -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
RGraphM_init.o:RGraphM_init.cpp:(.rdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `RGraphM_run_graph_match(SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*)'
```

($(GRAPHM_OBJ_REL) is a whole bunch of static C objects
This is the RcppExports.cpp

```
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <RcppGSL.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// run_graph_match
Rcpp::List run_graph_match(const RcppGSL::Matrix& A, const RcppGSL::Matrix& B, const Rcpp::List& algorithm_params);
RcppExport SEXP RGraphM_run_graph_match(SEXP ASEXP, SEXP BSEXP, SEXP algorithm_paramsSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const RcppGSL::Matrix& >::type A(ASEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const RcppGSL::Matrix& >::type B(BSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const Rcpp::List& >::type algorithm_params(algorithm_paramsSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(run_graph_match(A, B, algorithm_params));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

and this is the run_graph_match code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppGSL.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_permutation.h>

#include "graphm/graph.h"
#include "graphm/experiment.h"
#include "graphm/algorithm.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

// declare a dependency on the RcppGSL package; also activates plugin
// (but not needed when ’LinkingTo: RcppGSL’ is used with a package)
//
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL,Rcpp)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List run_graph_match(const RcppGSL::Matrix& A, const RcppGSL::Matrix& B, const Rcpp::List& algorithm_params){
// .. body
}
```

Comment: One thing that bothers me is that Rcppexports.cpp  does not have 
    // [[register]]
as suggested [here][1]
Should Rcpp do this automatically? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42507045/394963

Comment: Please show the definition of `RGraphM_run_graph_match()`. I suspect you are doing something wrong there irrespective of the registration aspect.

Comment: And yes, Rcpp 0.12.11 will do this automatically for you (under some conditions, ie wont't replace an `src/init.c` file you already had etc pp).

Comment: edited question to include body of RGraphM_run_graph_match().

Comment: No, that is the code that was generated for you. I was asking for the code *you* wrote, ie the function where your `[[Rcpp::export]]` tag sits.

Comment: I added the run_graph_match code.

Comment: Not sure. This may be your other problems. It is a link issue, but you have a non-standard `src/Makevars`.

Comment: I agree the issue is likely related  to me using non-standard src/Makevars. One thing I am wondering is if any special magic is taking place when the registering source code is compiled and linked. I think I will take a better look at Writing R extensions.